# How do I set permissions for IUSR to mysql so my C++ cgi script doesn't return error 502.2?

Tags: visual-c++, console-application, cgi, mysql-connector, mysql-8.0

I've got some legacy code I'm trying to update. So it's mysql 8.0 on Windows 10 64 bit. I am using visual studio 17 CE to compile my projects. I am using the headers from the "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include\";"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\" folders and I've added dependencies for the mysqlcppconn.lib; libmysql.lib libraries and added additional directories. The code will compile but at runtime it prints then exits if I include any call to a mysql function such as  mysql_get_client_info();  Even if the function is not being called it exits returning error 502.2 to my browser. Merely including this function in the code causes it to exit. Then if I run the program from a command prompt it prints to stdout 6.1.11. As expected. So, I feel like I need to set permissions for my IUSR Client to get to the mysql drivers? But, how do I do that? Thanks for any ideas?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "mysql.h"

void CheckMyDB(MYSQL* mysql) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", mysql_get_client_info());
}
```

I would expect it return the webpage generated by my script. But instead when I include the function to get client info it exits unexpectedly causing 502.2 error to be returned.  Since it runs as a console app I suspect permissions with the IUSR account and mysql driver is rejecting  the request causing a premature exit. But I don't know which files I need to set permissions on? Just the dll's ?  And which ones? Or am I missing something else?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use code boxes for code (don't put code into normal text). Furthermore, your code does not call `CheckMyDB()`, so how could we expect an output at all?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do I really need to put the call to mysql_get_client_info() in main() for you?

Comment: If you don't provide the *exact, original code* which produces the problem, you probably won't get the answer you want. You wouldn't be first one who tried to "simplify" his problem for "brevity" and "clarity" and thereby removed the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Finally fixed it by deleting the contents of:
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data and
C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces  Then re-importing my data. I think when I exported the data from the original db the first time it had an error. That probably caused the issue when I imported it. But everything is working swimmingly now.  Thanks..!!